# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start: Hangs if domain user account info not correct

Tags: vb.net

I have discovered that if the following typical code is used to start a process, and the user's logon info is incorrect in any way, the app will hang (even if try/catch is used) instead of reporting the error:

```
' Start the process
Dim ExecuteCommand As New ProcessStartInfo
ExecuteCommand.FileName = strCommandLine
ExecuteCommand.Arguments = strCommandLineArgs
ExecuteCommand.Domain = strDomainName
ExecuteCommand.UserName = strDomainAdmin
ExecuteCommand.Password = strDomainAdminPW ' SecureString password
ExecuteCommand.UseShellExecute = False
ExecuteCommand.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ExecuteCommand)
```

The code works great if the user didn't screw up his credentials.  If authentication fails, however, I need to inform the user.  However, I can't seem to contain the problem, the app just hangs like it's in some kind of mysterious loop that locks the app.

It is ridiculous for an app to crash just because a user gets a password wrong, and yet I have not been able to find anything online about this issue.

1. Is there a way to determine if user credentials have passed/failed an authentication test?
2. Is there a way to set some kind of timeout on a failed authentication attempt so the app just doesn't sit there in a hung state?
3. Is there proper error handling for this that actually works?

HUGE thanks to all you gurus, btw.  I almost NEVER have to ask questions in here because of so much life-saving and expert help you folks offer.

*NOTE: Using VB.NET 2010*

Comment: I'd just try `Process.Start(<pathToExe>)`

Comment: Actually, that is what is being passed, the variable to the exe file being setup elsewhere in the app.  But I have to use specific user permissions and conditions for proper execution.

Comment: I kind of hope you can't do this! Looks like a big security hole. The authenticated user should have the permission from the system to do the task.

Comment: I think you have it backwards.  Microsoft added these useful parameter capabilities to the process.start functionality to ENSURE authentication (security).  Not requiring authentication to start an admin-level process, actually, would be the wide-open security hole.